# db2 count(*) order by with hibernate criteria

Tags: db2, hibernate3

I tried this code:

```
List resultList = new ArrayList();
Criteria criteria = createCriteria(SystemLogFile.class);
criteria.add(Expression.eq("clientId", clientId));
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("systemLogFileId"));
if (page == -1) {
  resultList.add(criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult());
} else {
  criteria.setFirstResult(page * pageSize);
  criteria.setMaxResults(pageSize);
  resultList = criteria.list();
  setModelsListAsLoaded(resultList);
}
return resultList;
```

this code generate the following query:

```
select count(*) as y0_ from krn_system_log_file this_ where this_.CLIENT_ID=? order by this_.SYSTEM_LOG_FILE_ID desc
```

this works with oracle and mysql but not with db2!
I get this error msg:
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-119, SQLSTATE=42803, SQLERRMC=SYSTEM_LOG_FILE_ID, DRIVER=3.57.82

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Code -119](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00119n.html) means:

> An expression starting with *expression-start* specified in a SELECT
>   clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause is not specified in the
>   GROUP BY clause or it is in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER
>   BY clause with a column function and no GROUP BY clause is specified.

In DB2, if you want to order by `this_.SYSTEM_LOG_FILE_ID`, then that has to be in the `GROUP BY` clause. I don't use Hibernate, but can you add the `GROUP BY` to your `criteria` object?